# Android Studio - How to upgrade jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-jetpack-compose

I am currently using Android studio (2021.2.1 Patch 2). On choosing empty compose activity, the compose version being used is `1.1.0-beta01` .How can I upgrade it to `1.2.0-beta01` as the earlier one gives error while using LazyVerticalGrid? I am beginner to android. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the app/**build.gradle** file of the project :

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.courses"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"
}
```

Toplevel **build.gradle** file :

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.1.0-beta01'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.31' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have tried changing compose version in toplevel build.gradle file to `1.2.0-beta01` but the build of the project fails.

Please specify in comments if you need some more information.
Thanks

Comment: Try the same with `1.3.0-beta02`

Comment: How did you solve? Can you tell me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without seeing the compilation error message I can only guess at what might be the cause. But I see a couple of things that might give you problems.

The Compose Compiler for `1.2.0-beta01` requires Kotlin Plugin version `1.6.21` See [Compose Kotlin Compatibility Map](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin)

Additionally, from version `1.2.0` onwards they've introduced independent versioning for Compose Compiler from the rest of the Compose libraries, meaning that `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion` needs to point to a different version. As of right now the latest compiler version is `1.3.1` which needs kotlin plugin version `1.7.10`.

Try these changes.

```
ext {
    compose_version = '1.3.0-beta02' // or 1.2.1 if you want the latest stable version
}
```

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.3.1"
}
```

```
plugins {
    // others omitted
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}
```

Comment: Awesome!! Apart from the above changes, I had to change compileSdk to 33 (it needs at least 33) and it works. The compose kotlin compatibility map was really useful. Thanks!  One more thing, the changes that I am making are applied only to that project. Is there a way to make these changes global? I mean creating a new project should start with that compose version.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to edit the 'new project' templates. I'm on the latest Android Studio Electric Eel Canary 10 preview build and the 'empty compose activity' templates (they added another one for Material 3) there start with compose version 1.2.0 which is already out of date. These new libraries have so frequent updates that trying to keep on top of it is probably more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

- If anyone wants to read about the independent versioning for Compose Compiler from the rest of the Compose libraries, as mentioned in the previous answers. You can find the release notes [HERE](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/06/independent-versioning-of-Jetpack-Compose-libraries.html)